# How does evtree choose the root node? [R]

Tags: r, machine-learning, cart, party

I'm interested in understanding the mechanism of the Evolutionary Learning of Globally Optimal Trees or evtree in R.

Maybe I am missing something, but I don't understand how the root node is chosen for each tree. From my understanding the root node is randomly split for the first iterations, but is it itself also randomly chosen for each tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The evolutionary learning of trees as carried out by `evtree` is described in Grubinger, Zeileis, and Pfeiffer (2014), *Journal of Statistical Software*, **61**(1), 1–29. [doi:10.18637/jss.v061.i01](http://dx.doi.org/10.18637/jss.v061.i01)

Essentially, the idea is to have a population of trees, each of which is associated with a certain performance captured by a BIC-type criterion (i.e., loss function plus penalty term). All trees are initialized randomly, and also randomly varied from iteration to iteration, keeping only the best-performing trees in the population. After a certain number of iterations the overall best tree is returned. For all details see Section 3 of the above-mentioned paper.

So to answer your question about the split in the root node: It is the result of many random splits and random variations over the evolution of the tree.